# sum in numpy arrays with different dimension

Tags: python, arrays

I have a 3D numpy array with shape A=(10227,127,340) and a 1D with shape B=(10227), both array of float64. I just want to sum B to A(first column) at each of the 127x340 grid point.

The output array should be C(10227,127,340) with the values of the first column changed after the sum, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be one way of achieving it:

```
C = A + np.repeat(B, A.shape[1] * A.shape[2]).reshape(A.shape)
```

The following code also works but is much slower:

```
C = A.copy()
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    C[i:] += B[i]
```

Comment: The first option works perfectly, very simple and fast. Thank you very much Tarik.

Answer (score 0):

A more compact way of doing this uses `numpy`'s fancy [dimensional indexing tools](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#dimensional-indexing-tools):

`C = B + A[:,None,None]`

This automagically expands `A` to have the dimensions of `B| along the selected axes (indicated by` None`or`np.newaxis`)